# Blender to Unity Workflow - Blender Render or Cycles

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to streamline my workflow for modeling inside Blender and then exporting for use inside Unity. I just wanted to check on something.

If set to Cycles, Blender won't show me texturing on models until an appropriate material with 'image texture' source is setup.

If set to Blender Render, I can enable Textured Solid in the properties pane and import a image into the UV editor and instantly see results without the need to touch material setup.

To me it seems like Blender Render is therefore the fastest way to go for simple texturing and exporting for Unity. Am I right? Are there any advantages over Cycles that I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 3D game developing workflow you should not worry about the render engine since you won't use it. Render engine is only used if you want to produce final pictures in blender. Since you only want to produce 3D models (even with shader, texture etc...) you have no use of Cycle and you better stick with blender render.
You should understand that the render engine that matter for you is the one of Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I absolutely do understand that. It doesn't change the fact though that *if* Cycles is used, the workflow for textured asset creation is longer. So it does in fact matter which Blender render engine you use; and Blender Render is the best one.

Comment: That wasn't very clear but what I meant was that since you do not use the render engine for final result the better for you is indeed the most efficient in prototyping wich is Blender Render because it is one step shorter.

Comment: Yup. We're on the same page. Blender Render is the best thing to use for a shorter workflow. Ta!